# Can't save query in Netlify Graph

Tags: reactjs, next.js, netlify, netlify-function, netlify-cli

I am trying to create custom query for Spotify API using Netlify Graph, but I can't save the query. My query works as expected in graphql playground, the problem rises when I either try to save it or create handler for it.
Creating handler echoes this message in terminal without creating netlify function for handler:

```
Handling Netlify Graph: Generate handler as Netlify function ...
 »   Warning: Operation [object Object] not found in graphql, found: dac9c498-f1fc-4cac-ae1b-38a134c116ab}
 »   Warning: No handler was generated for operationId [object Object]
 »   Warning: No files generated for operation id: [object Object]
Finished handling Netlify Graph: Generate handler as Netlify function ...
```

I am quite new to Netlify and would greatly appreciate any help regarding fixing this problem.

Here is the query that I used:

```
query SearchQuery($search: String!) {
  spotify {
    search(data: {query: $search}, first: 10) {
      tracks {
        id
        name
        album {
          name
          images {
            url
          }
        }
        artists {
          name
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[Here is also the screenshot of the query.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fDYRn.png)

Comment: Never use images for code snippets, we never look at those! Accept my edit or else nobody would dare to answer... Also, welcome to StackOverflow!

Comment: Here's some to support my claim on this question not getting answers: [Should I use images with code snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/328542/should-documentation-use-images-with-code-snippets) [Why should I not upload...](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question)